# Google Maps API Multiple Markers with Infowindows - click events conflicting

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm trying to have a map with multiple markers each with an infowindow. 
Nothing fancy so far.

All infowindows should open onload. 
No problem.

And every infowindow should close if I click

1. on its own marker
2. on the X in its infowindow.

The latter is also no problem.

But if I click on the markers it behaves not as it should.

The page is loaded. The infowindows are open. Now I click Marker 1 and it closes the infowindow of Marker 2. If I click again Marker 1 an second infowindow opens on Marker 1. The "initial" infowindow on Marker 1 can only be closed with the X in the infowindow.

If I close all infowindows via the X then I can can open and close each infowindow via their markers. 
BUT: Opened infowindows will be closed from a click on the other marker, which is not what I want.
Only a click on their own marker should open and close the infowindow.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;  
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
   #map-canvas {
        height: 500px;
  width:800px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script>
 function initialize() {
     var infos = [];
  var locations = [
   ['Marker 1', 54.08655, 13.39234, 2],
   ['Marker 2', 53.56783, 13.27793, 1]       
  ];
  
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   zoomControl: true,
     zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
     }

  });
  
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    content: locations[i][0]
   });

   bounds.extend(marker.position); 
   
   var openedInfoWindow = null;
   
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();              

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function() {
       console.log('Klick! Marker='+this.content);
       if(openedInfoWindow != null){                       
        openedInfoWindow.close(); 
     openedInfoWindow = null;
    }else{      
       infowindow.setContent(this.content); 
       infowindow.open(map, this); 
       openedInfoWindow = infowindow;
       google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
       openedInfoWindow = null;       
      });
    } 

   }));
  
   
   
   
   google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
   map.setZoom(8);
   google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
  });
 }
 function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' + 'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
 }

 window.onload = loadScript;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is a [link to the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adsim/fz317jwe/6/)

It seems that the click events are conflicting, but in the moment I don't know how to change this.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example) didn't address my problem (please correct me if I'm wrong). The infowindows in it behave as follows: if you open a new infowindow via click on its marker the already opened infowindow of another marker is closed. That's not what I want. **Only a click on its own marker should close a infowindow not a click on another marker**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [post to which you link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example) does contain the solution: "function closure".  You just need to extend it to include the infowindow for each marker since you have a unique infowindow for each marker instead of a global infowindow shared among all the markers.

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        content: locations[i][0]
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i, infowindow) {
        return function () {
            console.log('Klick! Marker=' + this.content);
            infowindow.setContent(this.content);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        };
    })(marker, i, infowindow));
    bounds.extend(marker.position);

    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5am2Lzj/)

code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var infos = [];
  var locations = [
    ['Marker 1', 54.08655, 13.39234, 2],
    ['Marker 2', 53.56783, 13.27793, 1]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    }

  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      content: locations[i][0]
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i, infowindow) {
      return function() {
        console.log('Klick! Marker=' + this.content);
        infowindow.setContent(this.content);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      };
    })(marker, i, infowindow));
    bounds.extend(marker.position);

    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  var listener = google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
  });
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' + 'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah I already tried the closure thing, but it seems I missed something. ;)
Works like a charm. :)
https://jsfiddle.net/adsim/16Len8sh/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
function close_popups(){
  for(var i = 0; i<marker.length; i++){
    marker[i]['infowindow'].close();
  }
}
google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'click', function() {
     close_popups(); 
      this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
    });
```

Comment: Can you add a description to your answer? Clarification can help a lot.

Comment: This will help you in simultaneously popup close and open on marker click in google map.